# Calculate the date of Easter

Tags: code-golf, date

Your function or program should take a year as input and return (or print) the date (in the Gregorian calendar) of that years Easter (not the Eastern Orthodox Easter). The date returned should be formatted according to ISO 8601, but with support for years greater than 9999 (such as *312013-04-05* or *20010130*), and it only needs to work with years greater than or equal to **1583** (the year of the adoption of the Gregorian calendar), and years less than or equal to **5701583** (as that is when the sequence of Easter dates starts to repeat itself).

Examples:

```
e(5701583) = 5701583-04-10
e(2013)    = 2013-03-31
e(1583)    = 1583-04-10
e(3029)    = 30290322
e(1789)    = 17890412
e(1725)    = 17250401
```

The use of built-in functions for returning the date of easter is boring and therefore disallowed. Shortest answer (in characters) wins.

*Resources:*

- *http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Algorithms*
- *http://web.archive.org/web/20150227133210/http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/estralgs.txt*

Comment: Do you realise that some languages have a built-in function to do this?

Comment: Such as? The only one I am aware of is PHP, but the easter_date and easter_days functions are quite limited, easter_date only works for years after 1970 and easter_days doesn't return the correct amount of days for years prior to 1753. But I will edit the question to disallow the use of such functions.

Comment: R has a function `Easter` in package `timeDate` that works for any year of the gregorian calendar.

Comment: resource: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Algorithms

Comment: So this is Gregorian and NOT Julian? Also, I'm not Catholic, what is the "Catholic Tradition?"

Comment: What's the scoring method?  Fewest characters?

Comment: @jdstankosky, I wrote "according to the Catholic tradition" just to imply that it is Gregorian, I could perhaps clarify it a little.

Comment: Peter Taylor is correct. The function in Mathematica's Calendar package is `EasterSunday[year]`.  No, I won't be submitting it.

Comment: [More functions](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/estralgs.txt)

Comment: Bearing in mind that ISO 8601 doesn't naturally support years greater than 9999, is the answer required to support them?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, a good question. But I do think that the answer at least needs to support years up to 5,701,583, as that is when the cycle of dates recur (and it is doable using signed 32-bit integers). I will update the question and add a couple of test cases.

Comment: txt file link is an empty file.

Comment: @sergiol That's fixed now, I replaced the link with a version cached by archive.org, which should future proof it for quite a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### GolfScript (85 chars)

```
~:^100/.)3*4/.@8*13+25/-^19%.19*15+@+30%.@11/+29/23--.@-^.4/++7%97--^0@.31/100*\31%)+
```

Sample usage:

```
$ golfscript.rb codegolf11132.gs <<<2013
20130331
```

Note that this uses a different algorithm to most of the current answers. To be specific, I've adapted the algorithm attributed to Lichtenberg in the resource linked by [Sean Cheshire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5011/sean-cheshire) in a comment on the question.

The original algorithm, assuming sensible types (i.e. not JavaScript's numbers) and with an adaptation to give month*31+day (using day offset of 0) is

```
K = Y/100
M = 15 + (3*K+3)/4 - (8*K+13)/25
S = 2 - (3*K+3)/4
A = Y%19
D = (19*A+M) % 30
R = (D + A/11)/29
OG = 21 + D - R
SZ = 7 - (Y + Y/4 + S) % 7
OE = 7 - (OG-SZ) % 7
return OG + OE + 92
```

I extracted a common subexpression and did some other optimisations to reduce to

```
K = y/100
k = (3*K+3)/4
A = y%19
D = (19*A+15+k-(8*K+13)/25)%30
G = 23+D-(D+A/11)/29
return 97+G-(G+y+y/4-k)%7
```

This approach has slightly more arithmetic operations than the other one (Al Petrofsky's 20-op algorithm), but it has smaller constants; GolfScript doesn't need to worry about the extra parentheses because it's stack-based, and since each intermediate value in my optimised layout is used precisely twice it fits nicely with GolfScript's limitation of easy access to the top three items on the stack.

Comment: It has a small issue, when the date of Easter lies between the 1st of april and the 10th of april, it returns dates such as 1725041, when it should return 17250401. But upvoted for the different approach!

Comment: @Fors, oops. Now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 - <strike>125</strike> <strike>120</strike> 119 chars

This is [Fors's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11146/2621) shamelessly ported to Python.

```
y=input()
a=y/100*1483-y/400*2225+2613
b=(y%19*3510+a/25*319)/330%29
b=148-b-(y*5/4+a-b)%7
print(y*100+b/31)*100+b%31+1
```

**Edit**:  Changed last line from `print"%d-0%d-%02d"%(y,b/31,b%31+1)` to save 5 characters.  I would have loved to represent `10000` as `1e4`, but that would produce floating point necessitating a call to `int`.

**Edit2**:
Thanks to Peter Taylor for showing how to get rid of that `10000` and save 1 character.

Comment: If you split `10000`up to `100*100` you can put the last line into Horner's form as `(y*100+b/31)*100+b%31+1`. The leading parenthesis allows you to remove the space after `print`, and you can pull out the three instances of `100` to a variable for an overall saving of 1 char.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Excellent suggestion.  Updated my answer.

Comment: You can make it a function `e(y)` and save a few bytes

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 154

**150** chars if I switch to YYYYMMDD instead of YYYY-MM-DD.

```
<?$y=$argv[1];$a=$y/100|0;$b=$a>>2;$c=($y%19*351-~($b+$a*29.32+13.54)*31.9)/33%29|0;$d=56-$c-~($a-$b+$c-24-$y/.8)%7;echo$d>31?"$y-04-".($d-31):"$y-03-$d";
```

With Line Breaks:

```
<?
$y = $argv[1];
$a = $y / 100 |0;
$b = $a >> 2;
$c = ($y % 19 * 351 - ~($b + $a * 29.32 + 13.54) * 31.9) / 33 % 29 |0;
$d = 56 - $c - ~($a - $b + $c - 24 - $y / .8) % 7;
echo $d > 31 ? "$y-04-".($d - 31) : "$y-03-$d";
```

Useage: `php easter.php 1997`
Output: `1997-03-30`

Useage: `php easter.php 2001`
Output: `2001-04-15`

Comment: Great algorithm golfing, not so great code golfing. I took the freedom to chop off 18 bytes: `<?=$y=$argv[1],"-0",3+$m=($d=56-($c=($y%19*351-~(($a=$y/100|0)*29.32+($b=$a>>2)+13.54)*31.9)/33%29)-~($a-$b+$c-24-$y/.8)%7)>>5,31*$m-$d;`

Comment: Fails to meet output format. The leading zero for the day is missing where needed. E.g. for year 1725 it outputs `1725-04-1` instead of `1725-04-01`.

Answer (score 4):

## dc: 106 characters

```
?[0n]smdndsy100/1483*ly400/2225*-2613+dsa25/319*ly19%3510*+330/29%sb148lb-5ly*4/la+lb-7%-d31/0nn31%1+d9>mp
```

Usage:

```
> dc -e "?[0n]smdndsy100/1483*ly400/2225*-2613+dsa25/319*ly19%3510*+330/29%sb148lb-5ly*4/la+lb-7%-d31/0nn31%1+d9>mp"
1725
17250401
>
```

This should be able to be shortened by using 'd' and 'r' instead of all the loads and stores.

Answer (score 3):

## C: <strike>151</strike> 148 characters

```
y;a;b;main(){scanf("%d",&y);a=y/100*1483-y/400*2225+2613;b=(y%19*3510+a/25*319)/330%29;b=148-b-(y*5/4+a-b)%7;printf("%d-0%d-%02d\n",y,b/31,b%31+1);}
```

And the same code, but better formatted:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int y, a, b;

int main() {
    scanf("%d", &y);

    a = y/100*1483 - y/400*2225 + 2613;
    b = (y%19*3510 + a/25*319)/330%29;
    b = 148 - b - (y*5/4 + a - b)%7;

    printf("%d-0%d-%02d\n", y, b/31, b%31 + 1);
}
```

There are frightfully many algorithms for calculating the date of Easter, but only a few of them are well suited for code golfing.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript <strike>162</strike> <strike>156</strike> 145

```
function e(y){alert(y+"0"+((d=56-(c=(y%19*351-~((b=(a=y/100|0)>>2)+a*29.32+13.54)*31.9)/33%29|0)-~(a-b+c-24-y/.8)%7)>(f=31)?4:3)+(d-f>0&d-f<10?0:"")+(d>f?d-f:d))}
```

Inspired by @jdstankosky's PHP solution...
Provides YYYYMMDD result...

Now narrowed down to:

```
alert((y=prompt())+0+((d=56-(c=(y%19*351-~((b=(a=y/100|0)>>2)+a*29.32+13.54)*31.9)/33%29|0)-~(a-b+c-24-y/.8)%7)>(f=31)?4:3)+(d-f>0&d-f<10?0:"")+(d>f?d-f:d))
```

Now asks for input... reduced literal string of "0" to 0 and let loose typing work to my advantage! :)

Reduced further to take ES6 into account...

`e=y=>y+"0"+((d=56-(c=(y%19*351-31.9*~((b=(a=y/100|0)>>2)+29.32*a+13.54))/33%29|0)-~(a-b+c-24-y/.8)%7)>(f=31)?4:3)+(d-f>0&d-f<10?0:"")+(d>f?d-f:d)`

Answer (score 2):

### APL 132

This algorithm calculates the number of days Easter lies relative to the beginning of March. The date is returned in the YYYYMMDD format as allowed in the question:

```
E y                                                   
(a b)←⌊((3 8×⌊y÷100)+¯5 13)÷4 25                           
c←7|y+(⌊y÷4)-a-e←⌊d-((19×d←30|(227-(11×c)-a-b))+c←19|y)÷543
+/(10*4 2 0)×y,(3+i>31),(61⍴⍳31)[i←e+28-c]
```

Taking the original test cases:

```
      E 2013
20130331
      E 1583
15830410
      E 3029
30290322
      E 1789
17890412
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript 134 Characters

Using a slightly modified Al Petrofsky's 20-op algorithm to allow a simpler conversion into the year-month-date format.

This provides additional 14 characters shorter code from the answer provided by [WallyWest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8555/wallywest)

### The Original Al Petrofsky's Code:

```
    a =Y/100|0,
    b =a>>2,
    c =(Y%19*351-~(b+a*29.32+13.54)*31.9)/33%29|0,
    d =56-c-~(a-b+c-24-Y/.8)%7;
```

Last line changed to:

```
d =148-c-~(a-b+c-24-Y/.8)%7;
```

### 1. 138 Characters With the format YYYY-MM-DD

```js
e=y=>(c=(y%19*351-31.9*~((b=(a=y/100|0)>>2)+29.32*a+13.54))/33%29|0,d=148-c-~(a-b+c-24-y/.8)%7,y+'-0'+(d/31|0)+"-"+((o=d%31+1)>9?o:'0'+o))

console.log(e(2021));
console.log(e(2022));
console.log(e(5701583));
console.log(e(2013));
console.log(e(1583));
console.log(e(3029));
console.log(e(1789));
console.log(e(1725));
```

### 2. 134 Characters With the format YYYYMMDD

```js
e=y=>(c=(y%19*351-31.9*~((b=(a=y/100|0)>>2)+29.32*a+13.54))/33%29|0,d=148-c-~(a-b+c-24-y/.8)%7,y+'0'+(d/31|0)+((d=d%31+1)>9?d:'0'+d))

console.log(e(2021));
console.log(e(2022));
console.log(e(5701583));
console.log(e(2013));
console.log(e(1583));
console.log(e(3029));
console.log(e(1789));
console.log(e(1725));
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 179 bytes

```
READ*,I
J=I/100*2967-I/400*8875+7961
K=MOD(MOD(I,19)*6060+(MOD(MOD(J/25,59),30)+23)*319-1,9570)/330
L=K+28-MOD(I*5/4+J+K,7)
WRITE(*,'(I7,I0.2,I0.2)')I,(L-1)/31+3,MOD(L-1,31)+1
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvBDoIwEETv/RG67dbutpbSAwcTOBRQE2Li2QveNCH@PwLGw0zeTPKm9/yZHy/znH6wLGN7ahRm0dXZMpFyqYwm2@OKVRWDjqlk0dfnayO3ZOQEqqSStPx/nXUBQwL0BNp5UJ6TYUwhEljvSQx1r11ldl8Fe9Sd7jGCuI/51kqFhcwRMx3cXlBARjkYXmXWHjdtXegZNIv20iyLI66@)

Uses the "Emended Gregorian Easter" algorithm (Al Petrofsky) from the second resource link. Strangely, it fails for year 5701583 (and, apparently, only for this year), predicting the Easter as one week earlier. Prints the date in `YYYYYYYMMDD` format, with some leading spaces if the year has less then seven digits.