# Chinese Zodiac of the year

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, date

2015 was the year of the goat! In this challenge, you will figure out which animal represents the year. To avoid making this challenge to complex you won't need to calculate Chinese new year.

Because they are only 12 animals in the Zodiac, your code will need to be as short as possible.

### Examples

**Your program must get the system year**, the first line is just for reference

```
2015
Goat

1924
Rat

1923
Pig

2008
Rat
```

### Specification

The order of the Zodiac is:

```
Rat, Ox, Tiger, Rabbit, Dragon, Snake, Horse, Goat, Monkey, Rooster, Dog, Pig
```

`Rat` starts at 2008, `Pig` is 2007, `Ox` at 2009, etc. at the end this loops back around.

Output must be correctly capitalized.

Comment: Is anything before 2008 is assumed to be `Rat`?

Comment: @ZachGates no, that's just an example. I'll update

Comment: Can it use the year in the user's timezone?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 yes, of course

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19041/8478)

Comment: I am confused by the system year requirement. So there is no input? So in 2015, it would have printed goat, and now, it should print Monkey?

Comment: @TanMath yes, there is no input, your program should get the year from system time. For 2016, it should print Monkey, for 2017, Roster, then Dog for 2018, then 2019 would be Pig, then back to Rat in 2020

Comment: For actual usage: Chinese Zodiac consider a year starts at 立春 (transcription: lichun, literal: start of spring). Lichun is the day when the Sun is exactly at the celestial longitude of 315°, which is typically around Feb 4th. So for example, 2008-02-04 ~ 2009-02-02 is the year of Rat instead of 2008-01-01 ~ 2008-12-31. And there also be some people treat a year starts by Chinese new year. If so, the year of Rat is 2008-02-07 ~ 2009-01-25.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, 54 bytes

```
@rR3c."ayÖÚ©*ÐPk<`eüµÜxþ!¬Ì ¾½hÑðÙBwp"\c.d3
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40rR3c.%22ay%02%C3%96%06%C3%9A%C2%A9*%C2%9B%1B%C3%90Pk%3C%1B%60e%C3%BC%C2%B5%0B%C3%9Cx%C2%80%C3%BE!%C2%AC%16%C3%8C%C2%8C%20%C2%BE%C2%BDh%C3%91%C2%89%C3%B0%C3%99B%C2%9Bwp%22%5Cc.d3&debug=0)

You can replace the last 3 chars `.d3` with any year number to test the other Zodiac animals.

#### Explanation:

```
     ."ayö..."        packed string, decrypts to "monkeycroostercdogcpig..."
    c         \c      split this string at "c"s
 rR3                  make the first letter of each animal uppercase
                .d3   current year
@                     take the correct animal of the list and print
```

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth - 65 bytes

```
@c." y=CÅQ¯@îR
°©ÀáëªfÞ­#[õNqÀN8Ô'¼ô,n7Ë¶~fB").d3
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40c.%22+y%0B%3DC%17%C3%85Q%C2%95%0F%C2%87%C2%AF%40%1D%C3%AER%0A%C2%B0%C2%A9%C3%80%C3%A1%C3%AB%C2%AAf%1A%C3%9E%C2%AD%23%5B%C3%B5%C2%96%C2%8BN%13%C2%9C%C2%98q%C3%80%C2%99N8%C2%84%C3%94%27%C2%BC%C3%B4%2C%C2%9E%04n7%C3%8B%C2%B6%7EfB%22%29.d3&debug=0).

```
@                     Modular indexing
 c           )        Split string, use default of spaces
  ."ajs&^asd"         Packed string to compress space separated zodicas
 .d3                  Current year
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: @TanMath its really simple, but sure

Comment: You can save at least 3 bytes by narrowing down the character space. [demo](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40cr.%22+Y%04%C3%A16%C2%89%C3%8C%11%C2%97d}y%C3%B3%C3%B5%3D%C3%8C%C3%8A%C2%8E%C3%A4%C3%AE%1F%C2%A1%05%04%2B%C2%9Ekv%23%3BrU4%C2%94V%C2%B0%1Ch%C2%8D3~%23]Z%27%C3%85%C2%9D2%C2%8B%C3%B0B%224%29.d3&debug=0) Also, you might want to post the unprintable code as a hexdump and include a printable version.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>106</s> <s>105</s> <s>104</s> 103 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to Maltysen, 1 byte to insertusernamehere, *and* 1 byte to edc65!

```
x=>"RatOxTigerRabbitDragonSnakeHorseGoatMonkeyRoosterDogPig".match(/.[a-z]+/g)[new Date().getYear()%12]
```

Pretty self explanatory.

Comment: I feel like that string could use some btoa and atob. (You can also change the byte encoding, if that's allowed).

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ `btoa`s result looks to be 1.5x or more the length of the hardcoded string.

Comment: No, use atob to encode, and btoa to decode.

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ Oh. That's cool.

Comment: You would do `btoa\`[encoded gibberish here]\``, which should save at least 20 bytes.

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ It will save 20 characters but the encoded string is 66 bytes `E«t;«Ñn+t¶ ¢}©Ðz+±í¡«t2ä{-¢-z½¢` which is the same as the non-encoded so it's actually worse when you add `btoa\`\``.

Comment: That's why I recommended that the byte encoding be changed to ISO-8859-1 if possible.

Comment: You can save *1 byte*: Remove the `0` as separator and use this regex to split the string: `/(?=[A-Z])/`. Happy New Year. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere Nice regex! (I though of using `.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g)` but yours is 3 bytes shorter.)

Comment: `match(/.[a-z]+/g)` instead of split (added value: split with capture is not ES6, is a FireFox only feature)(and 1 byte shorter)

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>82</s> <s>80</s> 75 bytes

<s>This is was a direct port of [my Milky Way answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68324/39462).</s>

```
"Monkey Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat"S/et0==
```

*Saved 7 bytes thanks to [NinjaBearMonkey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29750/ninjabearmonkey).*

Comment: You can use `S` as a variable for space.

Comment: Even shorter: `"Monkey Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat"S/et0==`

Answer (score 3):

### [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/), <s>72</s> 65 bytes

```
`Mkey RooÐP Dog Pig R Ox Tig Rabb Dg Snake HÆ  Go`¸gÐ i %C
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=YE2Na2V5IFJvb9BQIERvZyBQaWcgUoUgT3ggVGlngCBSYWJiiiBEn2eNIFNuYWtlIEjGoCBHb4VguGfQIGkgJUM=&input=)

Comment: Umm... this is pretty good, but there's definitely some unprintables in there. Could you give us a link?

Comment: @Eth eh, didn't account that unprintable are stripped. Gonna restore it :D

Comment: BTW, instead of `$[$Ð i -4 %12]`, you can use `g(Ð i -4 %C`.

Comment: @Eth ok, and i'll dispose of -4 also, by changing the element order.

Comment: @Eth Wait, your fix doesn't appear to work, outputs NaN...

Comment: Yeah, I messed it up slightly. Try this: `gÐ i %C`

Comment: @Eth Yup, this one works.

Comment: `C` equals `12` ;)

Comment: @Eth lol ok, golfing another answer now :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Milky Way 1.6.1](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), <s>101</s> 96 bytes

```
M" "\=A12n"Goat Horse Snake Dragon Rabbit Tiger Ox Rat Pig Dog Rooster Monkey"" "\;>=<&{~1-;^};!
```

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to a reminder by [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo).*

---

#### Explanation

The code modulos the system year by 12 and outputs the proper animal.

---

#### Usage

```
./mw <path-to-code>
```

Comment: Maybe you can avoid `2008-` by rearranging the string as in my answer?

Comment: Oh, I think you already do that in your CJam answer

Comment: You're right! I can use the string from my CJam answer in reverse. Thanks for reminding me @LuisMendo

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 85 bytes

```
'Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat Monkey'YbZ'10H$XOU12X\)
```

Uses [release 6.0.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/6.0.0) of the language/compiler. Works in Octave.

#### Example

```
>> matl
 > 'Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat Monkey'YbZ'10H$XOU12X\)
 >
Monkey
```

#### Explanation

Note that the initial string is cyclically displaced by 3 to avoid a subtraction.

```
'Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat Monkey'
Yb                    % split at spaces
Z'                    % number representing current date and time
10H$XO                % get year as a string
U                     % convert to number
12X\                  % modulo 12, with 0 converted to 12
)                     % index (and implicitly print)
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 69 bytes

```
"SKiN<lEz=2)aFBY8H[$h-0|4=K`T2Cp%-a)o6"132b26b'`f+'`/et0==(eu\
```

Contains a bunch of unprintables. [Try it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22SKi%0E%08N%3C%0C%1ClEz%3D2)aFBY8H%5B%24h-0%7C4%05%3DK%60T2%7FCp%25%02-a)o6%22132b26b'%60f%2B'%60%2Fqi%3D(eu%5C&input=2016)

Comment: You can't take a year as input, it has to use the current system time.

Comment: Ah, fixed. @Maltysen

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>126</s> <s>116</s> 112 bytes

**Edit:** I'm keeping the other answer because it's cool, but this is shorter.

```python
from time import*
"Monkey Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Goat".split()[localtime().tm_year%12]
```

If trailing whitespace is ok, then it's 126 bytes. If not, it's 134 bytes after adding `.strip()` to the end of the code.

```python
from datetime import*
"MRDPROTRDSHGoooiaxiarnoonoggt gbaaraks    ebgkstet    rioee ye     tn    r"[datetime.now().year%12::12]
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 119 bytes

```
scan(t="Monkey Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat",w="")[(format(Sys.Date(),"%Y"):1)[1]%%12+1]
```

`format(Sys.Date(),"%Y")` returns the year as a character string, `(format(Sys.Date(),"%Y"):1)[1]` is the shortest way i could think of to coerce it into an integer so that we can apply `%%` to it (the sequence generator `:` indeed coerces automatically to integer). `+1` because R indices are 1-based and not 0-based.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP >= 5.6, 84 bytes

Very straight forward:

```
<?=[Monkey,Rooster,Dog,Pig,Rat,Ox,Tiger,Rabbit,Dragon,Snake,Horse,Goat][date(Y)%12];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python <s>129</s> 126 bytes

**EDIT**: I just learnt s.split(' ')=s.split()

Although this isn't the shortest method, here is an alternative answer to @Sherlock9's one:

```
from datetime import*
print 'Monkey Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat'.split()[date.today().year%12]
```

[Try it here](http://ideone.com/XgSbHI)

Comment: Wow. I just edited my answer and that was pretty close to what I edited it to. I'm going to try something with `time` next.

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, 92 bytes

```
(-split"Monkey Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat")[(date).Year%12]
```

Similar in spirit to other answers, added here only for sake of cataloging. This takes the string `"Monkey ... Goat"` and `-split`s it on spaces to create an array, which is cheaper than specifying the elements individually with `("Monkey","Rooster",...)`. We index into that array with the current `year` mod `12`, which outputs the result. Nothing too fancy.

Answer (score 0):

### C# 159

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){Console.Write("Monkey;Rooster;Dog;Pig;Rat;Ox;Tiger;Rabbit;Dragon;Snake;Horse;Goat".Split(';')[DateTime.Now.Year%12]);}}
```

Readable / ungolfed version

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Monkey;Rooster;Dog;Pig;Rat;Ox;Tiger;Rabbit;Dragon;Snake;Horse;Goat".Split(';')[DateTime.Now.Year % 12]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/contents.htm), 78 bytes

```
(>;:'Monkey Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat'){~12|
```

Usage:

```
    (>;:'Monkey Rooster Dog Pig Rat Ox Tiger Rabbit Dragon Snake Horse Goat'){~12| 2015
 Goat
```

Explanation:

```
;:      separates the string into boxed array according to the spaces
>       opens the boxed array so that it becomes a normal array
x {~ y  is choose the y-th element from x.
        the ~ reverses the argument, so x { y is choose the x-th element from y.
12|     is the residue when the year is divided by 12
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 49 bytes

```
`⌊ẇ ₃¼ Roos≠∴ •∞ Ḣ⟩ ₀⌊ Ox ṗȦ ₈Ė ėɾ Ċṅ ½√`⌈kD⌊12%i
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%E2%8C%8A%E1%BA%87%20%E2%82%83%C2%BC%20Roos%E2%89%A0%E2%88%B4%20%E2%80%A2%E2%88%9E%20%E1%B8%A2%E2%9F%A9%20%E2%82%80%E2%8C%8A%20Ox%20%E1%B9%97%C8%A6%20%E2%82%88%C4%96%20%C4%97%C9%BE%20%C4%8A%E1%B9%85%20%C2%BD%E2%88%9A%60%E2%8C%88kD%E2%8C%8A12%25i&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
`...`         # Compressed  string of names
     ⌈        # Split on spaces
      kD⌊     # Current year
         12%  # Modulo 12
            i # Index into list of names
```