# Which Western Zodiac sign is today?

Tags: code-golf, date

- Task:
  With the minimum amount of bytes, determine today's Zodiac sign using the programming language of your choice.
- Rules:
  This is code golf, the answer with the fewest characters wins. The initialization of getting the current date into a variable (e.g. `var now = new Date();`) does not add to the count. Leap years must be handled correctly.
- Limitations:
  You cannot use any other library functions for handling dates, nor predefined lists. In particular, participants would have to calculate the ordinal day of the year themselves if needed.
- Input:
  The current date in the proleptic Gregorian calendar with numeric year, month (1–12) and day of the month (1–28…31).
- Output:
  A single Unicode symbol indicating the current one of the twelve Zodiac signs from Western astrology, as used in horoscopes and listed below:

1. ♈︎ Aries: March 21 – April 19
2. ♉︎ Taurus: April 20 – May 20
3. ♊︎ Gemini: May 21 – June 21
4. ♋︎ Cancer: June 22 – July 22
5. ♌︎ Leo: July 23 – August 22
6. ♍︎ Virgo: August 23 – September 22
7. ♎︎ Libra: September 23 – October 22
8. ♏︎ Scorpio: October 23 – November 22
9. ♐︎ Sagittarius: November 23 – December 21
10. ♑︎ Capricorn: December 22 – January 19
11. ♒︎ Aquarius: January 20 – February 18
12. ♓︎ Pisces: February 19 – March 20

The actual dates might differ by one day depending on the year, but for this task the above date ranges are considered accurate for every year.

### Example

The sign for today, 28 February 2022, is Pisces, so the correct output would be `♓︎`.

### Related challenges

- [Chinese Zodiac of the year](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68318/chinese-zodiac-of-the-year)
- [What's the current zodiac?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193991/whats-the-current-zodiac) (hour)
- [Get the day of the year of a given date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230712/get-the-day-of-the-year-of-a-given-date)
- [ASCII Art of the Day #4 - Zodiac Signs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/ascii-art-of-the-day-4-zodiac-signs)
- [What is your star-sign?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35036/42932) – different output

Comment: The rule about _getting the current date into a variable_ is [an assumption about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/58563), which should be avoided. You should probably just stick to standard I/O rules. Also, it's currently a bit unclear what the input exactly is. Can we just take a month and a day? (Translating that into a zodiac sign is the core of the challenge anyway.)

Comment: To me, it sounds like the input to your code is the day, month, and year, all one-indexed; any code that gets the current date using language facilities does so only to format that date as input to the code. I do agree that it's a bit poorly explained in that regard.

Comment: I did not want to give languages that have a global `now` object or something like that an advantage, so if your language does not have something like that, you can still assume that there is a variable that has this information. You are right that this boils down to: you have a month number and a day number.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35036/what-is-your-star-sign)

Comment: Thanks @DigitalTrauma I assume there would be a challenge like this but did not find the one you are linking to. However, with symbol output I expect slightly different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“£f{ẋ’b5⁸ị+19>_@⁸_3%12+⁽#1Ọ
```

A dyadic Link accepting an integer, `month`, on the left and an integer, `day`, on the right that yields a character.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDi9OqH@7qftQwM8n0UeOOh7u7tQ0t7eIdgOx4Y1VDI@1HjXuVDR/u7vn//7/xfyNDAA)** Or see [a whole year](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDi9OqH@7qftQwM8n0UeOOh7u7tQ0t7eIdgOx4Y1VDI@1HjXuVDR/u7vl/ePmjxp3WDienP9q4Tt/a4eHOad6akf//R0cb6hgbxupEG@kYWQIpYwjPRMfYAEiZQnhmEJ45hGcBoSwhgoYGEK6hIZRvBOLHAgA).

#### How?

```
“£f{ẋ’b5⁸ị+19>_@⁸_3%12+⁽#1Ọ - Link: M; D
“£f{ẋ’                      - 53343748
      b5                    - to base five -> [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3]
        ⁸ị                  - get the item at 1-indexed index M
          +19               - add nineteen to it
             >              - is that greater than D? -> 1 or 0
              _@⁸           - subtract from M -> M-1 or M
                 _3         - subtract three (offset since characters start at March)
                   %12      - modulo twelve
                       ⁽#1  - 9800
                      +     - add
                          Ọ - cast to character
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>64</s>  62 bytes

Expects `(month)(day)`.

This version builds the UTF-8 encoding of the code point (from `0xE2 0x99 0x88` for Aries to `0xE2 0x99 0x93` for Pisces).

```javascript
m=>d=>Buffer([226,153,136+(m+=9^d<24+~"1342321"[m%12])%12])+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDdCoIwFMDx@55CgnBjFp6zaQ7Si15DCsSPKNSFVpe9uum6mhuDXfz5bePsUXyKsRzuz9e@V1U9NenUpVmVZud309QDyRHjACIeAI8Z6Vgqr9UJBftugQvkCNu82wFeqN6Y70@l6kfV1odW3UhDPKAEQ@oxz58X8@aClEBC6WYFlywNyPVRCy4ZDCj0UQsK6@nIfWNk3RjrYsElowGPulhwydyAiRsmFpRuKNcQQifU2YTghmBBdE6tszk1/D98@gE)

#### ES6, 63 bytes

Using the more straightforward `String.fromCharCode()` with a direct code point is one byte longer.

```javascript
m=>d=>String.fromCharCode(9800+(m+=9^d<24+~"1342321"[m%12])%12)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDPCoMgHMDx@54igjFFFv6stoTVpUfYcWwQ/Vsjc1TsuFdv5k6mCB6@flT0VXyKqRy793wcZFUvTbqINKvS7DqP3dAGzShF/izGXC0inlBKkCApf1QXFpGvD2HEQgb@TeyB3bGa8FLKYZJ9HfSyRQ3yACNGsUe8gxrEU4VhBAnGuw1cMzdgqLdacM1gwEhvtWBkXR27T4ytE0@6WHDNzIBnXSy45tCAiRsmFuRuyLcQqBPqbEJwQ7Agc75aZ/PV8P/w5Qc)

Comment: what does Buffer do?

Comment: Buffers are related to strings.

Comment: @DialFrost Buffer is a Node thing. And what really should be used here is [`Buffer.from(array)`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromarray), followed by `.toString('utf8')`.

Comment: I like how you used standard programming language and didn’t need many more bytes than others with golfing languages.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 112 bytes

```
T`d`k-m`1.-
T`d`l`.-
T`b-m`c-mb`.-3|[bce]-2|[df]-2[1-9]|[gm]-2[2-9]|[h-l]-2[3-9]|c-19
.(.).+
$1
T`e-mb-d`♈-♓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncw7DsIwDIDhPedgACFHsVOguQdbVCn0wUO0HRBjD8DO1Ov1IsE26vLns1v51b0f4yXnc2rTE4aEFoy4T4qaVw0MNU9@inXTVUBTbK/8RIRQTfE2iEl9h14GL0MDGIzd2p3dmw3yqY7PQJuW@QPL/M3ZofzBJWccAZbaICW21z0XjSt0X@jmAFhI/5avx7Vk3GmtN65Ul@qgDmJ0Yikb1agmuSOlHw) Link includes test cases. Takes input in the format `mm-dd`. Does not output a Unicode variation selector, but the output looks fine in TIO to me. Explanation:

```
T`d`k-m`1.-
```

Change October to December to `k` to `m`, which will become Scorpio to Capricorn.

```
T`d`l`.-
```

Change January to September to `b` to `j`, which will become Aquarius to Libra.

```
T`b-m`c-mb`.-3|[bce]-2|[df]-2[1-9]|[gm]-2[2-9]|[h-l]-2[3-9]|c-19
```

Increment the encoded sign if the day is past the cutoff date for the next sign.

```
.(.).+
$1
```

Delete everything except the encoded sign.

```
T`e-mb-d`♈-♓
```

Decode to a Unicode Zodiac sign.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
Ｎθ℅⁺⁹⁸⁰⁰﹪⁺⁸⁺θ›Ｎ⁺¹⁸Ｉ§”)⊞⌊4\`ζ”θ¹²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDGSifmFwCFAvIKS3WsLQwMNBR8M1PKc3Jh4hY6CiA6UIdBfei1ESQSmSTNKHShkB1zonFJRqOJZ55KakVGkrGhgZGhkbGJiCgpKNQqAkCOgqGRiDa@v9/Iy4ji/@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes separate month and day as inputs. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                           First input as a number
              Ｎ              Second input as a number
             ›               Is greater than
                    ”...”    Compressed string `310212344444`
                   §         Cyclically indexed by
                         θ   Input month
                  Ｉ          Cast to integer
               ⁺             Plus
                ¹⁸           Literal integer `18`
           ⁺                 Plus
            θ                Input month
         ⁺                   Plus
          ⁸                  Literal integer `8`
        ﹪                    Modulo
                          ¹² Literal integer `12`
   ⁺                         Plus
    ⁹⁸⁰⁰                     Literal integer `9800`
  ℅                          Convert to Unicode
                             Implicitly print
```