# Calculate the ISO week of Gregorian Easter

Tags: code-golf, date

As in [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11132/42932), your task – should you choose to accept it – is to calculate the **date of Easter Sunday** according to the [Gregorian Computus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_of_Easter) (as used in the Catholic Church and most others) when provided with only a year number as input, in as few characters as possible without relying on *Easter-specific* date functions possibly available in you language of choice.
The output shall be simply the two-digit number (12…17) of the **week of the year** according to ISO 8601-1 (without prefixed `W`), where weeks start on Monday and the first week of the year has 4 January (or the first Thursday) in it.

### Functions allowed

You *may not* use library functions that implement an algorithm for the Computus, like PHP's `easter_date()`, `EasterSunday[year]` from the Mathematica Calendar package or `Easter` from the R package `timeDate`.
You *may* use other predefined date functions, e.g. to find the day of the week or the week of the year.

### Contemporary example *input: output*

- 2001: 15
- 2002: 13
- 2003: 16
- 2004: 15
- 2005: 12
- 2006: 15
- 2007: 14
- 2008: 12
- 2009: 15
- 2010: 13
- 2011: 16
- 2012: 14
- 2013: 13
- 2014: 16
- 2015: 14
- 2016: 12
- 2017: 15
- 2018: 13
- 2019: 16
- 2020: 15
- 2021: 13
- 2022: 15
- 2023: 14
- 2024: 13
- 2025: 16
- 2026: 14
- 2027: 12
- 2028: 15
- 2029: 13
- 2030: 16
- 2031: 15
- 2032: 13
- 2033: 15
- 2034: 14
- 2035: 12
- 2036: 15
- 2037: 14
- 2038: 16
- 2039: 14
- 2040: 13
- 2041: 16

The returned value *must* be correct for years 1583 through 9999. It *should* be correct beyond that, but errors outside this range will not disqualify an answer. However, in the unlikely case of a tie, the answer with the wider range wins.

### Resources

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Algorithms)
- [R.H. van Gent](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Egent0113/easter/eastercalculator.htm)
- [ESTRALGS.TXT](http://web.archive.org/web/20150227133210/http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/estralgs.txt) has various algorithms

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861) I've voted to close this question as unclear as it is missing some key details (it lacks an objective winning criterion, and you should define when Easter is without relying on another question). For future reference, we strongly recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main.

Comment: What are "Easter-specific date functions"?

Comment: @pxeger This does have a winning criteria - code golf. See both the tag and "in as few characters as possible" in the challenge body

Comment: _it should be correct from 0030 through +99999 (and possibly beyond)_ : this part should either be removed or turned into a strict requirement. I think it's a better idea to limit the input to the range 1583-9999, though.

Comment: @Arnauld I've rephrased the requirement for the range of valid years. Note that the question that inspired this one required correct results for the whole cycle of 5.7 million years.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I've also elaborated on this requirement.

Comment: I believe this is very close to the [linked question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11132/42932), potentially to the point of being a duplicate. However, as my vote would close it unilaterally, and I'm not fully convinced they are duplicates, I'll hold off until/if other people believe that same

Comment: I believe there are considerable opportunities to safe some bytes due to the reduced number of possible results.

Comment: @Crissov That comment gets auto generated by duplicate votes, sorry about that

Comment: I've added a [similar question to the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/23650#23650).